# How to find proportion of values for vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, logic

For the following vector:

x <- rchisq(df =3, n = 1000)

How could I find the proportion of values greater than or equal to 7 in R?

Tried using the porp() function with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

To count the number of values equal or greater than 7 you can use table() function:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rchisq(df =3, n = 1000)
table(x>= 7)
FALSE  TRUE 
  929    71
```

to convert to proportion use prop.table() function from base R:

```
prop.table(table(x >= 7))

FALSE  TRUE 
0.929 0.071
```

here 92.9% of the x values are less than 7 and 7.1% are equal or greater than 7.

Answer (score 2):

In many programming languages, R included, `TRUE` and `FALSE` are interpreted as `1` and `0` when you do math on them. This means that when you `sum()` a condition you get a count of `TRUE` values, and when you `mean()` (average) a condition you get the proportion of `TRUE` values. So `mean(x >= 7)` gives the proportion of `x` values that are greater than or equal to 7.